# Using nav2d in React

Tags: reactjs, ros

I am trying to use nav2d in a create-react-app application. The dependencies (easeljs, ros2d and roslib) can be found as npm packages. How do I modify/configure the nav2d.js to use in a React app as currently I am receiving a module not found error when I have

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var ROSLIB = require('roslib');
var ROS2D = require('ros2d');
var NAV2D = require('nav2d');
var createjs = require('createjs-easeljs');

export default class TestMap extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    //Connect to ros
    var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
      url : 'ws://192.168.1.114:9090'
    });
    // Create the main viewer.
    var viewer = new ROS2D.Viewer({
      divID : 'nav',
      width : 750,
      height : 800
    });

    // Setup the nav client.
    var nav = NAV2D.OccupancyGridClientNav({
      ros : ros,
      rootObject : viewer.scene,
      viewer : viewer,
    serverName: '/move_base'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="nav"></div>
    )}
}
```

in the js file that is the react component.
The nav2d.js contains

```
var createjs = require('createjs-easeljs');
module.exports = NAV2D
```

The original nav2d file can be found at http://static.robotwebtools.org/nav2djs/current/nav2d.js 
(It is too long for here)

Thank you.

Comment: I somehow cannot find nav2d package in npm registry. Show your package.json

Comment: There is no npm package for nav2d. How do I use it without a npm package or how do I build a npm package?

Comment: There is a react package wrapper for nav2d, https://github.com/yodahuang/react-nav2djs but I've tried to get it to work with no avail... doesn't look supported any longer

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your public/index.html

```
    <script src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/EaselJS/current/easeljs.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/current/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.js"></script>

<script src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/ros2djs/current/ros2d.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/nav2djs/current/nav2d.js"></script>
```

Then In Your file just before using NAV2D

```
let NAV2D = window.NAV2D;
```